# How to delete a value in a struct?

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to delete a "user" from the struct on my code.

For example, this is the struct I have:

```c
struct clients {
   char name[30];
   int year;
   float amount;
};
```

And this is the two outputs I have:

```
Name: Victor
Birth Year: 1998
Amount: 1000.00
```

```
Name: John
Birth Year: 1996
Amount: 1500.00
```

What I want to do is to delete John and all his information from my struct.

I am trying to learn dynamic memmory allocation, so I used this command:

```c
clt = (struct clients*) malloc(n * sizeof(struct clients));
```

In my case I wish to write a command on case 3 that delete john from the struct, but I really can't figure out how to do that, I guess maybe using realloc? But I didn't even get close to write something it would work.

Here is my entire code so far:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct clients {
    char name[30];
    int year;
    float amount;
};

int main() {
    struct clients *clt;
    int option, n, d = 0;
    char name[30];

    printf("Welcome, Choose an option to begin:");

    do {
        printf("\n1 - Create a new list;\n");
        printf("2 - Find a person in the list;\n");
        printf("3 - Delete a person from the list.\n");
        printf("4 - End the program.\n");
        scanf("%d", &option);

        switch (option) {
            case 1:
                printf("\nType how many clients you want to register:");
                scanf("%d", &n);

                // allocating memory for n numbers of struct person
                clt = (struct clients*) malloc(n * sizeof(struct clients));

                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    printf("Type the name and the birth year:");
                    // To access members of 1st struct person,
                    scanf("%s %d", (clt + i)->name, &(clt + i)->year);

                    printf("\nType the amount:");
                    scanf("%f", &(clt + i)->amount);
                }

                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Type the name you want to find:");
                scanf("%s", name);

                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    if (strcmp(&clt[i].name, name) == 0) {
                        printf("\nThats the name:");
                        printf("\nName: %s\n", (clt + i)->name);
                        printf("Birth Year: %d\n", (clt + i)->year);
                        printf("Amount: %.2f\n", (clt + i)->amount);
                        d++;
                    }
                }

                if (d == 0)
                    printf("This name doesn't exist\n");
    
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
        }
    } while (option != 4);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing elements from dynamic arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097678/removing-elements-from-dynamic-arrays)

Comment: Avoid buffer overflows: `scanf("%29s", name);`, and *always* check the value returned by scanf.  (eg `if( scanf("%29s", name) != 1 ){ fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n"); ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to discard the element from its location in the list by moving the contents in the remainder of the list up , and overwriting the target element.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    if (strcmp(&clt[i].name, name)==0)
    {
        printf("\nThats the name:");

        printf("\nName: %s\n", (clt+i)->name);
        printf("Birth Year: %d\n", (clt+i)->year);
        printf("Amount: %.2f\n", (clt+i)->amount);
        d++; // This seems to be your sentinel value?
    }

    if ( 1 == d && i+1 != n ) // if the sentinel is set, but we're not off the end of the list yet
    {
        memcpy(clt+i, clt+i+1, sizeof( struct clients )); 
    }
}

n--; // reduce the list length
```

You could do this in one `memmove` call if you prefer. As @Neil says in the comments, `memmove` is tolerant of overlapping source and destination.

```
if ( 1 == d && i != n-1 ) // if the sentinel is set, but we're not off the end of the list yet
{
    memmove(clt+i, clt+i+1, (n-i-1) * sizeof( struct clients )); 
    break; // break for i
}
```

Comment: `memcpy`: "If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behaviour is undefined." Best use `memmove`, which doesn't have this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing almost a [dynamic array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) such as C++'s `std::vector`. It is static, but it could be a dynamic array without that much extra work. You could create a container, and split `n` into the container's `capacity` and `size`.

```
struct clients_array {
    size_t size, capacity;
    struct clients *data;
};
```

Instead of having multiple pointers, one could create a `struct clients_array` for each list. Sample code to deal with the `struct clients_array`.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>

/** `a` constructor with `n` spots. Returns true or false depending on whether
 it could be constructed. */
static int clients_array_reserve(struct clients_array *const a,
    const size_t n) {
    assert(a && n);
    if(n > SIZE_MAX / sizeof *a->data) return errno = ERANGE, 0;
    if(!(a->data = malloc(sizeof *a->data * n))) return 0;
    a->capacity = n;
    a->size = 0;
    return 1;
}

/** `a` destructor; call this when `a` has been successfully constructed. */
static void clients_array_(struct clients_array *const a)
    { if(a) { free(a->data); a->data = 0; a->capacity = a->size = 0; } }

/** Extract a new uninitialized entry out of constructed `a`. Returns null if
 there is no more space. */
static struct clients *clients_array_new(struct clients_array *const a) {
    assert(a);
    return a->capacity > a->size ? a->data + a->size++ : 0;
}

/** Remove index `rm` from `a`. */
static void clients_array_delete(struct clients_array *const a,
    const size_t rm) {
    assert(a && rm < a->size);
    memmove(a->data + rm, a->data + rm + 1,
        sizeof *a->data * (a->size - rm - 1));
    a->size--;
}
```

Then one can have different, independent arrays at once. If you want to update the code, say to allow `realloc` to increase the size of the object, you only need to modify the container.